# Using simple_list_item_checked, wherever I click it's getting checked

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I want to be able to click on every item on my list, and then move to another activity (this I know how to do)

And also when I click (exactly on the checkbox) then it should be clicked, because now, wherever I click on the item line, the checkbox is getting clicked.

I also want, once I click on any of the checkboxes, to get a count, because I want to put a progress bar, to show how far my students went in my book in the app,

```
String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chapters);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,android.R.id.text1, items);
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);

lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {
        CheckedTextView check = (CheckedTextView)view;
        check.setChecked(!check.isChecked());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are now checking the checkbox on the listView item click, if you want to do it on the checkbox click you should make your custom adapter instead of working with the default adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add checkbox in separate view of list or list item. For ex. if you have RelativeLayout then you can add your checkbox toLeftOf your listview that way your checkbox won't get clicked as you click on list item.

Answer (score 0):

So I guess it's not possible to make it get clicked when only clicking on it,

So I will try to make separate check boxes, as you suggested,

Any code idea for how to get all the check boxes values (count) so I can make a g